# Use different view depending on whether slug refers to user or group

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to create pages for individual users and groups with vanity URLs following the pattern `example.com/<user_or_group_name>`. Usernames and group names don't conflict. I set up the following URL pattern:

```py
path(route="<str:entity_name>", view=...)
```

I have two distinct views for user pages and group pages. I would like to use either view depending on whether `user_or_group_name` in the URL is a `Group` or a `User`.

```py
class GroupPage(DetailView):
    template_name = "userprofile/group_page.html"
    model = Group

class UserPage(DetailView):
    template_name = "userprofile/user_page.html"
    model = User
```

I understand that it is not possible to have to views on the same URL pattern.

I could build a unified view and choose object and template depending on whether `user_or_group_name` is a `User` or a `Group`. Yet that feels forced.

I thought about routing the URL to a dispatch function (below) but that returns `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'` raised by the `clickjacking` middleware.

```py
def page_dispatch(request, entity_name):
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=entity_name)
        return UserPage.as_view
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return InstitutionPage.as_view
```

How can I select the view based on whether the URL refers to a user or a group? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would advise to simply have different url patterns, this also has the benefit that your urls then are / can be _descriptive_, i.e. `example.com/user/<user_name>/` and `example.com/group/<group_name>/` feels much more user friendly than `example.com/<user_or_group_name>`

Comment: I'd usually agree, but here it's important to avoid `/user/` or `/group/` for the same (presumed) reason Github (https://github.com/gvanrossum, https://github.com/psf) does it: It allows you to refer to your published work and the URL works almost like a citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that you are returning the `as_view` method of the class. A view is always supposed to return a [`HttpResponse` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) (unless some exception is raised / occurs). What the `as_view` method does is it makes a function (this will act as the actual view) and returns that, so you can call `as_view` call the returned function and return that instead:

```
def page_dispatch(request, entity_name):
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=entity_name)
        return UserPage.as_view()(request, entity_name=entity_name)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return InstitutionPage.as_view()(request, entity_name=entity_name)
```

Although I would say separate url patterns for the two different pages is better, as that would then also allow users and groups with the same name to exist.

Comment: Thank you, that was so very helpful! Especially the explanation of `as_view()`.